# No module named 'cx_Oracle' only in CMD

Tags: python, spyder, cx-oracle

my problem is with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'" when I run connect_oracle.py from CMD in Windows 10.

```
#conncet_oracle.py

from __future__ import print_function
import os
import cx_Oracle
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("report/pass@ORA")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select sysdate from dual")
today, = cursor.fetchone()
print("The current date is", today)
```

But:

- when I install cx_Oracle I get

Requirement already satisfied: cx_oracle in c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (7.1.0)

- when I run connect_oracle.py in Python 3.7.2 Shell I get good result:

  exec(open('H:\Tasks\Python learning\connect_oracle.py').read())

result is The current date is 2019-02-18 11:08:01

- when I run it in Spyder I get also good result:

result is The current date is 2019-02-18 11:08:01

- when I run print(platform.sys.version) in spyder I get:

3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]

- when I run version.py in CMD I get:

3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:09:34) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)]

- when I run python -v in CMD I get:

Python 3.7.2

I am confuse from this all things. Is it possible that I have more version of Python and it is reason? 
How can I solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was maybe my mistake, but when I run in CMD:

*python connect_oracle.py*

I get good result, so problem is solved, potentially.

But it is weird for me, that in CMD I can run *version.py* without *python* with good result but *python connect_oracle.py* can be use only with *python* for good result. 
Why?